# Morse code converter only outputs one character c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the outputLabel to be a label control box where the morse code will output to. I am not sure why only the first morse code character is displayed but not the rest of the code. (if I type "cat" I only get first morse code character in outlabel)

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MorseCode

{
    public partial class morseCodeForm : Form
    {
        public morseCodeForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //Anthony Rosamilia
        //Make a key,value system to translate the user text. 
        //Make sure usertext appears only in lower case to minimise errors.
        private void convertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dictionary<char, String> morseCode = new Dictionary<char, String>()
            {
                {'a' , ".-"},{'b' , "-..."},{'c' , "-.-."}, //alpha
                {'d' , "-.."},{'e' , "."},{'f' , "..-."},
                {'g' , "--."},{'h' , "...."},{'i' , ".."},
                {'j' , ".---"},{'k' , "-.-"},{'l' , ".-.."},
                {'m' , "--"},{'n' , "-."},{'o' , "---"},
                {'p' , ".--."},{'q' , "--.-"},{'r' , ".-."},
                {'s' , ".-."},{'t' , "-"},{'u' , "..-"},
                {'v' , "...-"},{'w' , ".--"},{'x' , "-..-"},
                {'y' , "-.--"},{'z' , "--.."},
                //Numbers 
                {'0' , "-----"},{'1' , ".----"},{'2' , "..----"},{'3' , "...--"},
                {'4' , "....-"},{'5' , "....."},{'6' , "-...."},{'7' , "--..."},
                {'8' , "---.."},{'9' , "----."},
            };
            string userText = inputTextBox.Text;
            userText = userText.ToLower();
            for (int index = 0; index < userText.Length; index++)
            {
               /* if (index > 0)
                {
                    outLabel.Text = ('/').ToString();
                }
                */char t = userText[index];
                if (morseCode.ContainsKey(t))
                {
                    outLabel.Text = (morseCode[t]);
                }
            }
        }

        private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            inputTextBox.Text = "";
        }

        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
outLabel.Text = (morseCode[t]);
```

You're setting the Text property to a completely new value, not appending.  Wouldn't it be odd if that assignment *did* append a string to what was already there?

You need to preserve the old value:

```
outLabel.Text += morseCode[t];
```

That, however, creates a *new* string every time you append.  Better solution; build the string up with a `StringBuilder` first, i.e., a mutable string.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int index = 0; index < userText.Length; index++)
{
    var t = userText[index].ToLower();
    string morseValue;

    // no need for ContainsKey/[], use a single lookup
    if (morseCode.TryGetValue(t, out morseValue))
    {
        sb.Append(morseValue);
    }
}

outLabel.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: +1. Side note: `ToLower` may be useful as there is no upper/lower case Morse codes.

Comment: This is perfect. I thank you for your speed and multiple answers. I will try the more efficient path always.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Good call

Comment: While using `ToLower()` may be the best option in this case because you are working with `char` instead of `string` if you do work with strings and dictionaries pass a [case ignoring string comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase.aspx) to the [dictionary constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx) instead.